# Regular expressions in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, sequence, numeric

all.

I'm querying a Postgres 9.3 database looking for a specific pattern in a field:

```
SELECT
 P.id, P.processo_id, PR.num_formated
FROM
 publications P
INNER JOIN processos PR ON PR.id=P.processo_id
WHERE
 --The first numeric sequence must be exact 4 digits length, so the initial \d{4}
 PR.num_formated ~ '\d{4}[\.\-\\]\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d{1}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}'
AND
 P.id=781291700 --Just to force a specific record
```

where `PR.num_formated` is defined as `"character varying(255)"`. After being executed, the query returns:

```
  P.id      P.processo_id        PR.num_formated
781291700     502707245    20190001418-14.1998.8.05.0103
```

My question is: Why is Postgres "ignoring" the first \d? Is there any specificity in the form it interprets the regular expressions that differ from the "traditional/regular/orthodox/whatever" way, since the same regex works perfectly in another part of my system, but using a ruby code?

Thanks in advance

Walid

Comment: What is the expected output?  The result seems to match the regular expression you give.

Comment: You should write your example in a way that doesn't require us to have access to your computer in order to test it.  `select '20190001418-14.1998.8.05.0103' ~ '\d{4}[\.\-\\]\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d{1}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}' ;`

Comment: This regular expression behaves the same way in ruby as it does in postgresql.  I get a match for `ruby -le 'print "20190001418-14.1998.8.05.0103" =~ /\d{4}[\.\-\\]\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d{1}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 7 chars are ignored because the query finds the pattern as a part of the string. If you want to match the whole string use `^` and `$` [constraints.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE)

```
'^\d{4}[\.\-\\]\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\d{1}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$'
```

Comment: You're right, man. I don't believe I miss such basic thing. What a rookie mistake! Thanks for the patience.

Comment: This mistake is quite common and explainable because people more often use the `LIKE` operator which treats the matter differently.